# I would like to only select the second object in an array within a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

so I created a bar chart using Chart Js. So by using props I would like to change the labels of datasets one and two. The thing is my prop is set up in such a way due to the use in other graphs, that they have two objects inside. I only want to use, for example, object 2(in the object array) name for dataset two's label. I hope this makes sense.

I know you can use the map function to take all the object names, but I only want one..

```
                datasets: [
              {
                label: props.data.map((o) => o.Name),
                data: props.data.map((o) => o.Size),
                borderColor: 'rgba(181, 156, 201, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(181, 156, 201, 0.75)'

              },
              {
                label: props.data.map((o) => o.Name),
                data: props.data.map((o) => o.Size),
                borderColor: 'rgba(131, 90, 165, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(131, 90, 165, 0.75)',
              },
```

What the set up above gives me
[image: Bar Chart with two datasets]

This is my useState set

```
            setObjectOneIfo([InfoOne, InfoTwo])
```

And this is what I get in my console
[image: What I get in my console]

Maybe I'm missing something. Any help would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
          datasets: [
              {
                  label: props.data.map((o) => o.Name[1]), //Just put the index number you want behind name in square brackets
                  data: props.data.map((o) => o.Size),
                  borderColor: 'rgba(181, 156, 201, 1)',
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(181, 156, 201, 0.75)'

              },
              {
                 label: props.data.map((o) => o.Name),
                 data: props.data.map((o) => o.Size),
                 borderColor: 'rgba(131, 90, 165, 1)',
                 backgroundColor: 'rgba(131, 90, 165, 0.75)',
              }
```